# $4$-element subsets of the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots,10\}$ that do not contain any pair of consecutive numbers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, combinations

Find the number of subsets of the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots,10\}$ that contain $4$ elements and do not include any pair of consecutive numbers.

For example $\{1,2,5,7\}$ is not an example of such a subset since $1,2$ are consecutive. I think that we can set the $4$ cases to solve it, case one exactly $2$ numbers of consecutive elements, case two exactly $3$ numbers of consecutive elements, case three exactly $3$ numbers of consecutive elements and case four exactly $4$ numbers of consecutive elements, and we sum $4$ cases and minus them from all choices.

Comment: Note that it is possible to have two pairs of consecutive integers such as $\{1, 2, 5, 6\}$ in which the four numbers are not consecutive.

Comment: This case compute in case one

Comment: I think to this idea ,now  how we compute the subsets that contain 1?

Comment: There are nine pairs of consecutive numbers, those that begin with $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $7$, $8$, $9$.  We then pick two other elements in the set from the remaining eight numbers, giving us $9\binom{8}{2}$ four element subsets that contain a pair of consecutive numbers.  However, we have counted the $28$ pairs that contain two disjoint pairs twice (seven pairs associated with 1,2; six pairs associated with 2,3; five pairs associated with 3,4; and so forth), so the number of subsets that contain at least two consecutive numbers is $9\binom{8}{2} - 28 = 8\binom{8}{2}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig What about subsets which contain three consecutive numbers and a non-consecutive number? Wouldn't they still be double-counted? (e.g. $\{2,4,5,6\}$ would be counted as $4,5$ with $2,6$ as well as $5,6$ with $2,4$)

Comment: @Stobor  Yes.  After reading the preceding comments, it appears I was addressing the OP's omission of cases in which there are two disjoint pairs from his proposed solution.  I addressed both the cases of two overlapping pairs (three consecutive numbers) and two disjoint pairs in my answer to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Method 1:**  Let's apply your strategy of using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

There are $\binom{10}{4}$ four-element subsets of a ten-element set.  From these, we must exclude those subsets containing at least two consecutive numbers.

A string of at least two consecutive numbers in the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$ can begin with any of the nine numbers less than $10$.  Once we select a pair of consecutive numbers beginning with one of these nine numbers, we must select two additional elements of the ten-element set from the eight elements that are not in the pair of consecutive numbers, which we can do in $\binom{8}{2}$ ways.  Thus, it appears we have $9 \cdot \binom{8}{2}$ sets containing at least two consecutive numbers.  However, we have overcounted since we have counted sets containing two disjoint pairs twice.  There are $\binom{8}{2}$ such sets since we must exclude from the $\binom{9}{2}$ ways of selecting two of the nine numbers less than $10$ as starting points for the two pairs of consecutive integers the $\binom{8}{1}$ ways of selecting consecutive starting points that would prevent them from being disjoint.  Note that it is a consequence of Pascal's Identity that $\binom{9}{2} - \binom{8}{1} = \binom{8}{2}$.  Hence, there are
$$9 \cdot \binom{8}{2} - \left[\binom{9}{2} - \binom{8}{1}\right] = 9 \cdot \binom{8}{2} - \binom{8}{2} = 8 \cdot \binom{8}{2}$$
four-element subsets containing at least two consecutive numbers.

A string of at least three consecutive numbers in the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$ can begin with any of the eight numbers less than $9$.  Once we select a triple of consecutive numbers, we can select the remaining element in the subset from one of the seven elements in the set that are not in the triple, giving
$$8 \cdot \binom{7}{1}$$
four-element subsets that contain at least three consecutive numbers.

A string of four consecutive numbers in the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$ can begin with any of the seven numbers less than $8$.

Thus, by the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of four-element subsets of the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$ that do not contain consecutive numbers is
$$\binom{10}{4} - 8 \cdot \binom{8}{2} + 8 \cdot \binom{7}{1} - 7 = 35$$

**Method 2:** Here is a more efficient use of the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

As above, there are $\binom{10}{4}$ ways to select four of the ten numbers.  From these, we wish to exclude those selections which include one or more adjacent pairs of numbers.

*An adjacent pair of numbers*:  There are nine ways to select the smaller number in the pair of adjacent numbers.  Once that pair has been selected, there are $\binom{8}{2}$ ways to select two of the remaining eight numbers.  Hence, there are $\binom{9}{1}\binom{8}{2}$ selections that contain an adjacent pair.

However, we have subtracted each selection with two adjacent pairs twice, once for each pair we could have designated as the adjacent pair of numbers.  We only want to subtract them once, so we must add them to the total.

*Two adjacent pairs of numbers*:  There are two possibilities.  Either the pairs are overlapping, meaning that three consecutive numbers are selected, or they are disjoint.

Two overlapping adjacent pairs of numbers:  There are eight ways to select the smallest of the three consecutive numbers and seven ways to select one of the remaining seven numbers.  Hence, there are $\binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{1}$ such selections.

Two disjoint pairs of adjacent numbers:  Imagine that we have ten unmarked balls and two boxes that can each contain two balls.  We have eight positions to fill, two of which will be filled with boxes and the others with single balls.  We can select two of the eight positions for the boxes in $\binom{8}{2}$ ways.  Now, place the balls from left to right, with two in each of the two boxes.  Number the balls from left to right.  The numbers on the balls in the boxes are the two disjoint pairs of adjacent numbers.

However, if we add those selections containing two disjoint pairs to the total, we will not have counted selections containing three disjoint pairs at all.  That is because we first subtracted them three times, once for each way we could have designated one of the pairs as the adjacent pair of numbers, then added them three times, once for each of the $\binom{3}{2}$ ways we could have designated two of the three pairs as the two pairs of adjacent numbers.  Thus, we must subtract selections containing three adjacent pairs from the total.

*Three adjacent pairs of numbers*:  Since only four numbers are selected, this means that all four numbers must be consecutive.  There are seven ways to select the smallest number in the string of four consecutive numbers.  Hence, there are $\binom{7}{1}$ such selections.

By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of four-element subsets that do not contain a string of at least two consecutive numbers is
$$\binom{10}{4} - \binom{9}{1}\binom{8}{2} + \binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{1} + \binom{8}{2} - \binom{7}{1} = 35$$

**Method 3:** A more efficient approach is to arrange six blue and four green balls in a row so that no two of the green balls are consecutive, then number the balls from left to right.  The numbers on the green balls are the desired subset of four numbers, no two of which are consecutive, selected from the set $[10] = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$.

Line up six blue balls in a row.  This creates seven spaces, five between successive blue balls and two at the ends of the row.
$$\square b \square b \square b \square b \square b \square b \square$$
To ensure that no two of the green balls are consecutive, we select four of these seven spaces in which to place a green ball, which can be done in
$$\binom{7}{4} = 35$$
ways.  We now number the balls from left to right.  The numbers on the green balls are the desired subset of four numbers selected from the set $[10]$, no two of which are consecutive.

Comment: I am struggling Understanding **However, we have overcounted since we have counted sets containing two disjoint pairs twice.  There are $\binom{8}{2}$ such sets since we must exclude from the $\binom{9}{2}$ ways of selecting two of the nine numbers less than $10$ as starting points for the two pairs of consecutive integers the $\binom{8}{1}$ ways of selecting consecutive starting points that would prevent them from being disjoint.**

Comment: @mathophile While I would not solve the problem in the same way now, three consecutive numbers contain two overlapping pairs of adjacent numbers.  For instance, $1, 2, 3$ contains the adjacent pairs $1, 2$ and $2, 3$.  Since I did not want to count overlapping pairs of consecutive numbers, I subtracted them.  Removing overlapping pairs left me with the number of disjoint pairs that I wanted to subtract from the total.  That said, I wrote an updated Inclusion-Exclusion Principle argument (Method 2) in terms of adjacent pairs of numbers which I hope that you will find easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Since $ \binom{10}{4} $ is not a big number, we may use a brute-force approach and get the number $35$.
https://gist.github.com/mtp1376/32851179f609f182dd4d

Comment: This answer is hard

Comment: I've printed all consecutive combinations under the page.

Answer (score 1):

Final answer:

$$35$$

If we start with a simpler problem, of counting how many 4 element subsets there are of $\{1, \dotsc, 10\}$, then that's ${10 \choose 4}$. Another way of thinking about binomial coefficient ${n \choose r}$ is the number of $n$-character strings over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$ with $r$ $1$s. The equivalence of this is due to the fact that the $1$ tells you what's in the subset and the $0$ tells you what isn't. We'll use the latter picture now.

A $1$ can't be followed by a $1$ so must be followed by a $0$. So our alphabet will be $\{0,10\}$ instead of $\{0,1\}$. The extra $0$ after the $1$ stops you from including consecutive numbers. Our strings will have four $10$s and two $0$s, which makes the number ${6 \choose 2} = \frac{6 \cdot 5}{2} = 15$. We also need to include the strings which end in $1$, which means adding ${6 \choose 3} = 20$.

Comment: No, final answer is 35

Comment: @amirbahadory fixed

Comment: ,Because answer is 35,I complete don't read your answer ,you see answer upside.

Comment: @amirbahadory  This is a useful answer.  It is worth reading carefully, as is Brian M. Scott's answer to [How many $4$-element subsets of a given set contain no consecutive integers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153649/how-many-4-element-subsets-of-a-given-set-contain-no-consecutive-integers?rq=1).

Comment: very thanks,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let us leave $x_1$ nos before selecting the first no, then leave $x_r$ nos between the $(r-1)$st and $r$th no for $r= 2,3,4$, then leave $x_5$ nos. after the fourth no till the end.
Clearly $x_1 + \ldots + x_5= 10-4= 6$.
$x_1,x_5 \geq 0$ and $x_2,x_3,x_4 \geq 1$ for nonconsecutive. Let $y_1, y_5$ be $x_1$ and $x_5$. And $x_r - 1= y_r$ for $r = 2,3,4$ so that $y_r \geq 0$
Now $\sum y_r = 3$.
No of non negative integral solutions $= (3+5-1)C3= 7C3= 35$.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: It looks like you intended to say that the number of nonnegative integer solutions $= \binom{3 + 5 - 1}{3}$.